# Dwolla Custom Payment Buttons: Where does the data go?

Tags: shopify, dwolla

I'm currently integrating a Dwolla payment method hack on a Shopify store using a Dwolla  button.  The explanation of the hack is posted on the Shopify forums here:

http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussion/t/has-shopify-and-you-abandoned-dwolla-133714

(The hack is being used because Shopify doesn't currently support a viable Dwolla gateway option)

I finally did a live test in both guest checkout mode and checked out with an account signed in to Dwolla.

I don't see any of the transaction details when viewing the payment in my Dwolla account(the detail field is empty) despite having included the following button parameters:

- data-amount
- data-shipping
- data-tax
- data-name  (populated with the Shopify order #)
- data-desc  (populated with the Shopify Customer Name from Checkout)
- data-orderid (populated with the Shopify order #)
- data-notes  (populated with the customer's checkout note from the Shopify checkout)
- data-guest-checkout (true)

I had incorrectly assumed that `data-name`, `data-desc`, and/or `data-orderid` would populate information in the Dwolla transaction information in my Dwolla account's Payment Activity under Options:Details for the transaction.

My question is this: What happens to the `data-name`, `data-desc`, `data-orderid` information?
Is it retrievable on the Dwolla side?
Is there some way to populate the transaction details with any of the above identifiers?

Clarification:  When the customer arrives on the Dwolla secure payment page the identifiers do populate the fields properly.  My concern is that as the merchant, when I view the transaction in my business Dwolla account, there is no information that links the transaction to the Shopify order by either the order# or a matching customer name (if the name entered in the Dwolla payment process was different than the name entered in the Shopify checkout process).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only field that is viewable in the Transaction Details page of Dwolla.com is the data-notes. So, if you'd like to be able to correlate transactions, I would suggest adding the Shopify order ID to the data-notes. The data-orderId field is viewable in the [Transactions/ById()](http://developers.dwolla.com/dev/docs/transactions/byid) API call.

The data-name and data-desc, as you've already discovered, are only used at the time of checkout to list the products purchased.